# Basic Authorization not workingin AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, basic-authentication, ntlm

I am trying to do some Basic Authorization in Javascript but the Server always returns Error 401. It only works if I login with NTLM in my Browser. But I need to access this Server in my Web-App. In the response header it says:

```
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

Does this mean that I have to use NTLM? And if so, is there a way to do this in javascript for a Web-App?

i am Sorry, if this is just a stupid question, but I can't figure out what to do.

btw: The Server is with HTTPS, if that matters :)

Comment: Basic Authentication, not authorization.  If the server is asking for NTLM, then that's what it's configured to accept.

Comment: Okay thank you. So Basic Authentication won't work and I have to figure out how to do it in NTLM? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's looking to do HTTP Basic Authentication with NTLM. You can't do this out-of-the-box with anything other than Internet Explorer brand browsers. There's a fire fox plugin that does the LDAP integration however.

Doing NTLM auth is a three-way handshake, you're best off finding a pre-packaged library to do this for you, as programming the information is actually quite a pain.

Comment: Well thats not the answer I was hoping for,  but I guess it's the answer to my Problem. thank you ! :-) you don't happen to know any library for javascript to do this, do you?

Comment: I can't really think of any that will manage it for you, normally windows, LDAP and NTLM all work together and weren't built with the perception that you could do this. I can't remember the exact issue I had implementing but I hit a serious roadblock like not being able to transmit the right data. I'd honestly suggest checking out oAuth, the learning curve for something like that and time to implement will be smaller than trying to hack browsers to use NTLM (which has lots of security flaws anyway).

Comment: Well thanks for your effort and quick response! Now it all seems a bit more doable :-) I think I will check this out tomorrow.